# NodeJS no me imprime resultado

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

No me imprime los valores que hago de una petición. por consola me sale lo siguiente

(node:11272) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Conexión a BD exitosa! :)
servidor iniciado correctamente en la url localhost:3700

Mi script es el siguiente:

** INDEX.JS**

```
'use strict'
//conexion a la bd con mongoose

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = 3700;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/portafolio')
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("Conexión a BD exitosa! :)")
            app.listen(port,function(){
                console.log('servidor iniciado correctamente en la url localhost:3700');
            });
            //creación del servidor
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

** APP.JS **

```
'use strict'

//levantando el servidor nodeJS

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

//cargar archivo de rutas


//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS


//rutas
app.get('/', function (req,resp){
    resp.status(200).send(function(){
       "<h1> Bienvenido!</h1>"
    });
});

app.get('/test', function (req,resp){
    resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    resp.status(200).send(function(){
        message: 'Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS'
    });
});
// exportar

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Parece que te hace falta `http.listen`

Comment: Algo asi: `app.listen(3000, () => { console.log(escuchando); });`

Comment: Eso sería dentro de la ruta '/' ? No entiendo mucho como funciona node, gracias por ayudarme hermano.

Comment: En tu caso seria en el index, despues de llamar a la BD. También tienes que llamar a `var miApp = require('rutaHacia/app')` por que en realidad es un route. Lo pones en `index.js` despues de iniciar la BD y antes de `app.listen` con esta linea `app.use('/', miApp)`. Esto indica que cualquier ruta que no tenga nada va a llegar a tu route `miApp`

Comment: Uhm probe y no me funciono, aprecio mucho tu ayuda bro, seguire buscando

Comment: Comparte tu proyecto para revisarlo más a fondo. A lo mejor es una cuestión pequeña nada más.

Comment: https://github.com/edlopez111/backend.git

Comment: -no quiso copiarse la carpeta de node, pero  ese es mi codigo, el index.js y el app.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás enviando una función a tu frontend. Además la advertencia que estás recibiendo por consola al realizar la conexión a la base de datos es porque te hace falta pasar un parámetro como opción de conexión.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea poder enviar respuesta al frontend al recibir una petición HTTP usando un Servidor Node con Express y Mongoose.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Primeramente solucionaremos el mensaje de error que te aparece por consola al levantar el servidor, para ello vamos a cambiar algunas cosas en el archivo `index.js`, específicamente en el método en el que realizas la conexión.

**index.js**

```
'use strict'
//conexion a la bd con mongoose
// cambiamos 'var' por 'const', Node soporta let y const (ES2015) desde la versión 6.4.0
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');
const port = 3700;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// A continuación creamos el objeto de opciones que pasaremos a la conexión
// 'useNewUrlParser' se establece a 'true' y esto elimina la advertencia.
const mongooseOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/portafolio', mongooseOptions) // <= aqui pasamos las opciones que creamos anteriormente
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("Conexión a BD exitosa! :)")
        app.listen(port,function() {
            console.log('servidor iniciado correctamente en la url localhost:3700');
        });
        //creación del servidor
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1); // <= cerramos el proceso con un 'exit code' distinto de cero
    });
```

Con esto ya nos hemos quitado de encima la advertencia en consola que sugería usar `newUrlParser: true`. Puedes ver más información en [Mongoose - Connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

En cuanto al error de que no recibes la respuesta a tu solicitud, debemos realizar modificaciones en el archivo *app.js*.

**app.js**

```
'use strict'
//levantando el servidor nodeJS
const express = require('express');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //<= si usas Express 4.16.0 en adelante no necesitas importar esto, ya que por defecto viene como dependencia
const app = express();

//cargar archivo de rutas

//middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})); // se usa 'express.json()' y 'express.urlencoded()' en vez de 'bodyParser'
app.use(express.json());

//CORS

//rutas
app.get('/', function (req, res){ // <= usa 'req, res' no uses 'resp' debemos apegarnos al uso estandar
    res.status(200).send("<h1> Bienvenido!</h1>"); // <= si pones dentro de send una función, el resultado que esperas no será enviado en la respuesta
    // Además tu función escrita tal como la tienes no hace absolutamente nada
    });
});

app.get('/test', function (req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    res.status(200).send('Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS');
    });
});
// exportar

module.exports = app;
```

Como puedes apreciar en el código, tu error era la función que pasabas dentro del método `send`. Según la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) de Express, los objetos que puedes pasar al método `send` incluyen:

1. Un Objeto Buffer (`new Buffer('Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS')`)
2. Un Objeto JSON (`{message: 'Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS'}`)
3. Un String (`'Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS'`) o (`<H1>Hola mundo desde mi API REST en NodeJS</H1>'`)
4. Un Array (`['Hola', 'mundo']`)

En ningún caso se envía una función.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas,

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo de la advertencia si se solucionó, lo demás aun estoy en ello, ya había probado con el setHeader yno obtuve exito, probaré una cosa que encontre y te cuento como me fue, muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias hermano! funciono de maravilla. Saludos!

Comment: Un gusto amigo. Saludos