# Coneccion con mongoose no funciona acceder el puerto. No muestra cambios en consola

Tags: mongoose

Hace unas semanas hice mi primer consulta aca y me ayudar a resolver mis dudas.

Ahora vengo con lo siguiente. Estoy haciendo un curso de Javascript y en la parte de MongoDB hay una seccion donde se establece la coneccion con la base de datos, y luego se consulta si el puerto esta bien y ahi tira un console.log diciendo que todo esta correcto. Pero me tira un error: "(node:4424) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect."

Bueno, primero mi codigo:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = require('./app');
var port = 3700;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myApp')
    .then(() => {
        console.log("coneccion a la BD joya");

        //creacion del servidor
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log("Servidor corriendo correto");
        });

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

En el otro archivo:

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


//arvhicos de rutas

//middlewares

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS

//rutas

//exportar el modulo

module.exports = app;
```

Cuestion que ya intente cambiar la coneccion por:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myApp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Pero no funciona, no me tira por consola "Servidor corriendo correto". Si me tira el "coneccion a la BD joya". Tambien intente usando el puerto 3000.

Una cosa curiosa, es que si cambio el console log de "coneccion a la BD joya" por, no se, "coneccion a la BD joya pero cambiado", en la consola me sigue tirando "coneccion a la BD joya"... puede venir de ahi el error? Ayuda! Toda info se agradece.

Comment: En la linea donde tienes: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myApp')`, agrégale la opción sugerida por Mongoose: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myApp', { useNewUrlParser: true })`, además, ya que estamos, no uses `var` para declarar tus variables, debes usar `const` y `let`. Por último, muchos cursos sugieren usar `body-parser` como un middleware que se debe instalar usando `npm`, sin embargo, a partir de la versión 4.16 de Express, el mismo ya es parte de las dependencias, puedes hacer lo mismo usando `express.json()` y `express.urlencoded()`. Saludos

Comment: Checate esta respuesta de una duda como la tuya
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254277/nodejs-no-me-imprime-resultado